# Jdbc - can't connect to MySQL db on localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, gwt

I am a beginner in Java and I am trying to run a GWT app, which was not written by me, but I know the code should be working. When starting development server with `gwt:run`, everything seems to work but there is no DB connection and I am getting JDBC errors.

```
[ERROR] kwi 21, 2018 3:54:08 AM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[ERROR] WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[INFO] 2018-04-21 03:54:11,805 ERROR Could not perform database startup operations using logging manager [jdbcManager{ description=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, connectionSource=factory{ public static java.sql.Connection com.mcrawler.crawler.database.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection() }, tableName=EventLog, columns=[ { name=eventDate, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=level, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=logger, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=exception, layout=%ex{full}, literal=null, timestamp=false } ] }]. java.sql.SQLException: Failed to obtain connection from factory method.
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:107)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:53)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.startupInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:60)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.startup(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.start(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:89)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:168)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:175)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getContext(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:102)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:42)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:29)
[INFO]  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.<init>(Slf4jLog.java:38)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog.<init>(Slf4jLog.java:32)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.initialized(Log.java:161)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:435)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log.getLogger(Log.java:425)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.listener.ELContextCleaner.<clinit>(ELContextCleaner.java:43)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createListener(ContextHandler.java:2375)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createListener(ServletContextHandler.java:1227)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.newListenerInstance(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1908)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitListener(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1865)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:366)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1240)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:165)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:105)
[INFO]  ... 59 more
[INFO] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
[INFO]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
[INFO]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
[INFO]  at com.mcrawler.crawler.database.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
[INFO]  ... 64 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2983)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
[INFO]  ... 81 more
[INFO] 
[INFO] 2018-04-21 03:54:12,036 ERROR Could not perform database startup operations using logging manager [jdbcManager{ description=databaseAppender, bufferSize=0, connectionSource=factory{ public static java.sql.Connection com.mcrawler.crawler.database.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection() }, tableName=EventLog, columns=[ { name=eventDate, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=level, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=logger, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=exception, layout=%ex{full}, literal=null, timestamp=false } ] }]. java.sql.SQLException: Failed to obtain connection from factory method.
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:107)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:53)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.startupInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:60)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.startup(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.start(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:89)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:168)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:359)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:420)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:138)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:147)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:41)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:262)
[INFO]  at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:59)
[INFO]  at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:37)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.getLogger(Log4JLogger.java:262)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.<init>(Log4JLogger.java:108)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.createLogFromClass(LogFactoryImpl.java:1025)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.discoverLogImplementation(LogFactoryImpl.java:844)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.newInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:541)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:292)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.LogFactoryImpl.getInstance(LogFactoryImpl.java:269)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:657)
[INFO]  at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.<clinit>(JspServlet.java:58)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createServlet(ServletContextHandler.java:1075)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.newInstance(ServletHolder.java:957)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:514)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:344)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:791)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:265)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1242)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:494)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:541)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.doStart(RequestLogHandler.java:165)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:95)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:282)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:740)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[INFO]  at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.FactoryMethodConnectionSource$1.getConnection(FactoryMethodConnectionSource.java:105)
[INFO]  ... 54 more
[INFO] Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:360)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:924)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:870)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2064)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:790)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:377)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:395)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
[INFO]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
[INFO]  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:75)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
[INFO]  at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
[INFO]  at com.mcrawler.crawler.database.ConnectionFactory.getDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
[INFO]  ... 59 more
[INFO] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2983)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1873)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1802)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1206)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2234)
[INFO]  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2265)
[INFO]  ... 76 more
```

I have MySQL installed and have created database `crawldb` using `root` user. The password of the root user is `password`. I can login to MySQL from shell and can see the database. Here is the application code which seems to specify connection settings:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- MySQL localhost -->
        <property name='connection.driver_class'>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name='connection.url'>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/crawldb</property>
        <property name='connection.username'>root</property>
        <property name='connection.password'>password</property>
        <property name='dialect'>org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">15</property>
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">false</property>

        <property name="default_batch_fetch_size">128</property>
        <property name="jdbc.batch_size">24</property>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

In `pom.xml` there is a dependency for mysql-connector-java:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.34</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Try with your machine name or ip instead of localhost.

Comment: Are you sure that port `3306` is ok?

Comment: Which  version of MySQL are you using, and which version of MySQL Connector/J (full versions please!)

Comment: I just checked and port 3306 is correct. I am using MySQL Community Server 8.0.11. I am not sure how to check the Connector/J version, but it's the one which comes bundled with the MySQL version I am using. Also as noted in the original post, pom.xml has version 5.1.34 mysql-connector-java.

Comment: Found the Connector/J version installed, it seems to be the same as MySQL version, so 8.0.11.

Comment: I also just tried changing "localhost" to 127.0.0.1 and then to my internal IP but it didn't help.

Comment: If your pom mentions 5.1.34, then that is likely the version you are using, and not 8.0.11. You might want to doublecheck that. If it is still 5.1.34, then consider trying 5.1.46 or 8.0.11. Note that the 8.0.11 Connector/J is in the package `com.mysql.cj`, and your stack trace is not, which supports the idea that you're using an older one which might simply have bugs in combination with MySQL 8.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks a lot, MySQL version was exactly the problem here :) I ended up installing MySQL 5.5 on my machine, because I wanted to get the project running without any modifications to get as close to current production environment as possible. It connects fine now, I am facing a whole new set of issues with creating the correct schema but that's a different story... 

Are you going post the answer so I can mark it as a solution? Or shall I do it myself?

Comment: If you can post an own answer that is ok with me :)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, ok on it :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

As Mark Rotteveel suggested in the comments, the version of Connector/J in my `pom.xml` was pretty old (5.1.34) compared to MySQL version installed on my system (8.0.11), which turned out to be a buggy combination.

The solution was to either use newer version of Connector/J or downgrade the MySQL version on my machine. I ended up choosing the latter and installed MySQL 5.5 , because I needed to run the app without modifying any project files.